# IOS Enterprise App Unable to Install Please Try Again Later

Tags: ios, iphone

I know this question has been asked a lot on SO, however I can ensure that my case is different. I am unable to install any enterprise apps on this particular iPhone. It will download the app and then the app icon will go dark. When I tapped on the app, this error message pops out.
[image: Error]

The thing is, I know that the **IPA file, Provisioning Profiles, Certificate, manifest links, etc works** because I am able to install the apps on other devices.

My suspicions is some settings changed on that specific iPhone that somehow blocks enterprise apps.

**Things I have tried:**

- Restarting the phone multiple times.
- Checking the storage to ensure there is enough space.
- Successfully installed App Store applications.
- Removing the app via **General > iPhone Storage**, and tried installing it again.
- Make sure the time and date are valid and set automatically.

**Things that might help:**

- The **Developer** option on settings does not exist.
- After downloading the app, the **Device Management** option on settings does not appear.

**Note:**
Currently I have no physical access to the phone, so installing directly through Mac might be hard.

Please help me if you have any solution or have ever encountered this problem before. Thank you.

Comment: Do you try to remove the profile and reinstall it?

Comment: @QuangDam as mentioned above, I don't think there is any issue with the profile since all other devices can install the app even if they don't have any enterprise app in the first place.

Comment: Is the date and time correct on that device?

Comment: @Paulw11Good point. Let me check and get back to you.

Comment: @Paulw11 Checked the time and date, everything looks fine. It is automatically set and calendar is Gregorian.

Comment: I am facing same issue on one iphone 7 plus running on ios 13.3.1,  @The1993, did you found any solution?

Comment: @PlusInfosys sadly, no. The users changed phone and had no issue. Issue persist on the old phone

Comment: my client is using 7plus, and he is not going to change phone for this.  anyway, thank you for quick response.

Comment: @PlusInfosys the only thing I was not able to try is to reformat the phone to factory setting. Maybe you can try it if you are able to back up the phone in advance.

Comment: One of our customers is facing this issue, I can't ask him to reset the phone to install our application. So this will not work in my case.

Comment: For us it started happening 2 days ago and only on 2 out of many devices we use for testing. We are using Enterprise In House signing. @The1993 did you manage to resolve the issue or have any updates? Thanks.

Comment: For us also, it started on 18th June. Any solution?

Comment: For us, the ad-hoc certificate was expired. Created new ad-hoc and released. But with the older certificate it was working on some of the registered devices.

Comment: @MiroslavKovac I have not found any solution that works, I no longer have access to the affected iPhone so I can't confirm Ahmad Khani solution below works.

Comment: I was facing this issue for a long time but today I figured out the exact problem. Actually I was using a Swedish character (å) in my App name. When I changed it to plan "a", the App installed successfully. That worked for me and I am really glad. It may work for you too (if you are using any special character in your App Name, just try to remove it and then try to install the App).

Comment: For us it started working after half a day. We suspected it was an Apple issue as it was just a day before WWDC 2020.

Comment: This started happening to us as well on one of our Enterprise apps. We did notice a profile was expired, so I did renew that. I wasn't the one who released the original app so I can't 100% confirm that it was the exact profile used, but it expired yesterday and started occurring today, so it's likely. However, after renewing, still can't install. Any other updates or solutions?

Comment: Hello! Any updates here? I have the same issue. Distribution cert not expired, enterprise apple account not expired, in house export method, but grey app and same alert. Are there any changes apple made that would affect this? The app i cannot download is SwiftUI. Has anyone else distributed a swift ui application to unregistered devices?

Comment: Any solution for this?, i am facing the same issue on iOS 16.

Answer (score 13):

This exact error can be caused by a wrong bundle identifier in your manifest (the file that must be linked to in the `itms-services://` URL for enterprise downloads).

Make sure your `<key>bundle-identifier</key><string>...</string>` string value is correct / that it matches your actual deployed app contained in the .ipa file.
iOS 16 (and earlier betas in some cases) will download the app, then check the manifest and it mismatches with the .ipa contents then remove the download and show a placeholder for the app. A tiny cloud icon may appear next to the app which is in some sense a bug in iOS: iOS thinks it's an "offloaded app" because its contents was deleted due to a verification failure and when you tap the app, iOS will try to download it from the app store but fail because it's an enterprise app.

You can verify what went wrong is to connect your phone with a cable, open "Console.app", click your phone, click start streaming, and filter on "MIInstallerErrorDomain" or perhaps your expected bundle name. You may see something like "IXSErrorPresenter presentErrorForIdentities [...] The item being installed did not contain an app with bundle ID xxxx" which should hopefully lead you in the right direction. This error may appear during install or when tapping it. So play around in the console to troubleshoot the exact cause since multiple things can be wrong in the manifest (as others have pointed out)

Answer (score 5):

We had this issue on one of our apps, trying to OTA install on iOS 14 devices.
Worked with no issues before and all certificates and provisioning profiles are good.

Turned out that the .ipa url in the manifest .plist was using "http://" instead of "https://".

Comment: This was our issue as well. Legacy apps and old URLs just hiding in the plist file. Easy and quick to fix. Thanks, Bonzo.

Comment: This was mine too.  Can't believe I overlooked this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: For iOS 16 the restrictions are tightened by Apple for enterprise apps, over the air installation.

1. The plist file you get with the "app.ipa" file should have exact url to point to the .ipa file e.g https://yourserver.com/AppName/Subfolder/myapp.ipa
2. 57x57 app icon png file url should be correct.
3. 512x512 full size app icon file url should be correct.
4. **The app bundle should be exact as your registered AppId matching with xcode bundle id.**
5. 

If your fresh installed app icon turned grey and when you tap, it shows unable to install, that means you enterprise account membership is expired.[image: Unable to install xxx please try again later]
[image: Membership expired]

Comment: As I mentioned above, there is no issue with the enterprise membership / certificates since I can install the app on other phones.

Comment: In my case, existing installed apps work with expired membership, but as soon as I try to install fresh it shows above alert.

Answer (score 1):

Check if phone date and time is correct.

The same thing happened to me.
I tried everything and even changed the iCloud account but still couldn't install.
It turned out the phone in question had wrong date.

Answer (score 1):

First, the access address needs to be https.
Second, the download address of the PLIST access URL must be https.
Third, the IPA download link also needs to be https.
The above https protocol needs to be greater than TLS1.0, it is recommended to use TLS1.2 or above to prevent failure.
Of course, you also need to check whether the enterprise certificate has expired.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your ipa file and menifest file is in corrected and exist in directory of your site.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to `<key>bundle-identifier</key>` we needed to set `<key>title</key>` to the exact name of our application in the manifest (plist file)

If someone is using cordova: set `bundle-identifier` the same as `widget`'s `id` attribute and `title` to `name` element of the cordova's config.xml

Answer (score 1):

This thread was very helpful for me because of the stress placed on the correctness of the URLs in the plist file. I was pulling an ASP.NET MVC project out of mothballs and named a virtual directory differently from the controller name (Downloads vs. Download respectively). The plist needed the virtual directory and not the controller, so:

https://my.work.domain.com/Downloads/myapp.ipa <-- Downloads with an 's'

and not

https://my.work.domain.com/Download/myapp.ipa <-- no 's'

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue because of "update term and conditions, Please see in image url", after accept it by account owner, it will work fine. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsPAy.png, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've added your device UDID on your Apple Developer Account.
as you know you can't install an enterprise version on all devices.

Comment: That's not true... ad-hoc signing has this limitation, but enterprise should not.

Comment: I added the UDID still not able to download and install app.@Ahmad Khani

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you enterprise certificate is not expired, the build will work on devices that already have the certificate but you won't be able to install it on new devices.